# notificationManager get notification by Id

Tags: android, notificationmanager

Anyone know any way to get a notification by id? It's I want when get a new notification if it is still being shown in the status bar of Android want to get the information and add it to a new notification. Thank you.

Comment: Please, accept the second answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

NotificationManager doesn't give you a way to find existing notifications by ID. If you want to update a notification, post a new notification but use the same ID. It will either show it as new or update the existing notification with that ID.

Comment: This will replace the old notification?

Comment: Straight from the documentation: "If a notification with the same id has already been posted by your application and has not yet been canceled, it will be replaced by the updated information." https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#notify(int,%20android.app.Notification)

Comment: Thanks Karakuri, I solved my problem using sharedpreferences I store data in it and I use on update.

Comment: As of Marshmallow (SDK 23) this answer is no longer correct. See @hakanbing's answer about getActiveNotifications().

Answer (score 15):

You can get active notification list from NotificationManager.

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
public Notification getActiveNotification(int notificationId) {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    StatusBarNotification[] barNotifications = notificationManager.getActiveNotifications();
    for(StatusBarNotification notification: barNotifications) {
        if (notification.getId() == notificationId) {
            return notification.getNotification();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: requires API 23 and above

Comment: Shows only visible notifications, which have been posted by OS.

Comment: @Anup but this returns only partial data like title and text and do not return full object of notification

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @hakanbing the same in Kotlin.

```
fun getActiveNotification(context: Context, notificationId: Int): Notification? {
    val notificationManager =
        context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    val barNotifications = notificationManager.activeNotifications
    return barNotifications.firstOrNull { it.id == notificationId }?.notification
}
```