# Updating an android notification sequentially

Tags: android, notifications

I am building a messaging application that notifies users when a new message comes in.

Because this could happen several times a day (or several times an hour), I don't want to continually throw new notifications. Instead, if the user has not dismissed a notification, I would like to update it with the number of new messages pending (following the "Stacking" design guideline).

In the Android documentation, there is an example of updating a notification with a number:

```
mNotificationManager =
         (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
// Sets an ID for the notification, so it can be updated
int notifyID = 1;
mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
.setContentTitle("New Message")
.setContentText("You've received new messages.")
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notify_status)
numMessages = 0;
// Start of a loop that processes data and then notifies the user
     ...
    mNotifyBuilder.setContentText(currentText)
        .setNumber(++numMessages);
    // Because the ID remains unchanged, the existing notification is
    // updated.
    mNotificationManager.notify(
        notifyID,
        mNotifyBuilder.build());
...
```

HOWEVER, this seems to assume that you are maintaining this number within your application and outside of the notification manager / builder. For a host of reasons, this is very inconvenient (and brittle) in the context of my application.

I would like to know - is there any way to read the current number assigned to a message (the equivalent of mNotifyBuilder.getNumber()) ?

**FOLLOW-ON QUESTION:** If reading the current number is not possible, is there a way to know from a running service if a notification has been cancelled or manually dismissed by the user ?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? It might help if you show your own code!

Comment: It's hard to show a negative.... I was able to successfully get the notification working, and to update the notification. I can even add the number! However,  because I don't know when the notification has been dismissed, and because I don't know what the current number is, I don't know how to increment the number :( :(

Answer (score 0):

You notification is assigned with an ID. You can use this ID to cancel or update the same notification if it hasn't been cancelled by the user.

> Straight from the documentation: "If a notification with the same id
>   has already been posted by your application and has not yet been
>   canceled, it will be replaced by the updated information."

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23831214/notificationmanager-get-notification-by-id) and [that one](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#notify(int,%20android.app.Notification)).

Comment: Got that, and it's working fine. I am looking for a way to know the content of the notification associated with an ID before I update it (in this case, to know the number associated with the notification). Just being able to overwrite the notification doesn't help me.

Comment: Why do you need the old number? Just use the new one. The text will stay the same, right?

Comment: I wanted to be able to show the number of new messages in the notification, and have that number reset when the notification is dismissed. Unfortunately, it doesn't look like there is a way to do this :/