# Android: Get messages from a notification that uses MessagingStyle

Tags: java, android, push-notification, notifications

I want to get the messages that are shown in a `notification` that uses `MessagingStyle` in `Android`.

I already have the code to get the `notification` instance (android.app.Notification). I've seen that `NotificationCompat` has a function named `extractMessagingStyleFromNotification`, but I cannot use `NotificationCompat` because it doesn't support the `Person` class.

Is there any way to retrieve the messages that are currently shown in a certain notification without using `NotificationCompat`?

I know that one workaround is to store in memory the list of messages and update that list when a new message is received or the notification is clicked/dismissed. However, I'm developing a `Cordova` app and I have 2 different plugins displaying notifications. To make this workaround work both plugins should share this list, but the plugins are independent from each other so that's not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use [AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx) instead of Android Support Library, since the latter is no longer updated. With AndroidX I can use NotificationCompat because it supports the Person class, so I can use extractMessagingStyleFromNotification.

Comment: Just came here to add some more info, if you wanna get the current showing notification use this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47345498), since you should use the same notification id, you pass that to this function and you can get the current messages